# RackTables setting ownership and permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions, ubuntu-server, ownership

I am trying to install RackTables on a Ubuntu Server 13. I have followed all the steps on the documentation. When I get to the step after I connect to the database I cant seem to figure out the ownership settings. 
I have set up the database as follows :

```
mysql -uroot -p

create database racktables;
grant all on racktables.* to root;
grant all on racktables.* to root@localhost;
grant all on racktables.* to rackuser;
grant all on racktables.* to rackuser@localhost;
set password for rackuser@localhost=password('rackpw');
exit
```

Here is the step that I am stuck on;

## RackTables installation: step 4 of 7

> Please set ownership (chown) and/or permissions (chmod) of /var/www/racktables/inc/secret.php on the server filesystem as
>   follows:
>
> - The file MUST NOT be writable by the httpd process.
> - The file MUST be readable by the httpd process.
> - The file should not be readable by anyone except the httpd process.
> - The file should not be writable by anyone.
>
> For example, if httpd runs as user "nobody" and group "nogroup",
>   commands similar to the following may work (though not guaranteed to,
>   please consider only as an example):
>
> chown nobody:nogroup secret.php; chmod 400 secret.php

I have tried the

```
chown root:rackuser /var/www/racktables/inc/secret.php
chmod 400 /var/www/racktables/inc/secret.php
```

I cant figure out how to set up the permissions so that they fall into this category

- The file MUST NOT be writable by the httpd process.
- The file MUST be readable by the httpd process.
- The file should not be readable by anyone except the httpd process.
- The file should not be writable by anyone.

Please help. Any suggestion is appreciated 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to figure out which user and group your web server (Apache/nginx/etc) are running under.

If you're using Apache, you should be able to check by running:

```
grep -E '^(User|Group)' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In Ubuntu, it's common for both user and group to be www-data.

Once you know that, you should be able to change the file's ownership like:

```
chown [webserveruser]:[webservergroup] /var/www/racktables/inc/secret.php
```

Example:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/racktables/inc/secret.php
```

Keep the chmod the same as you had before.

This should mean it's readable by the www-data user and only the www-data user, writable by nobody (including www-data), which should mean all four of your conditions.